# Why .withSockJs seems to block Stomp over Websocket from connecting client with server

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket

I've struggled to connect the JS client with the Java server with a client using Stomp over WebSocket. The problem was fixed when I got rid of `.withSockJs()` while configuring `stompEndpoints`. Can someone explain to me what was the case here and why it happened? My understanding was that this method offers fallback but should not mess up a normal WebSocket connection.

#### Working alternatives:

```java
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat"); 
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat"); 
}
```

#### Notworking case:

```java
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
}
```

Also: I have noticed that adding `.setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:5050")` doesn't have any impact on communication in my case. I was able to connect to the server via a client on port `5050` but also via postman on `5555`. Before the problem with `withSockJs()` I struggled with a different problem related to CORS. The solution was to change the socket configuration on the client from SockJs to WebSocket but before finding this I tried many different approaches on the server side as I thought that my server implementation was the problem. I was working with `setAllowedOrigins`, but when I was finally able to connect I noticed that this method seems to not work.

One more question: How is the controller of WebSocket endpoints implemented? I want to keep track of active clients username to sessionId mapping. Do I need thread safe static map or all of messaging happen on a single thread? In other words, will there be more than one WebSocket controller instance if multiple clients are connected?

Comment: On Stack Overflow a question should focus only on a *single* problem. When you ask multiple questions it makes it difficult to identify a correct answer. For example, what if an answer only addresses one part of your question? Assuming that it's accurate, is it "correct"? What if there are 2 answers and they each accurately address different parts of your question. Which one is "correct"? This kind of ambiguity is bad for community involvement and devalues the content. Please ask questions that focus on a single issue. Thanks!